# TypeError: Input 'input_sizes' of 'Conv3DBackpropInputV2' Op has type int64 that does not match expected type of int32

Tags: tensorflow

```
deconv_shape1 = layer3.get_shape()
de_W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(4, 4, 4, 
deconv_shape1[4].value, 2), mean = mu, stddev = sigma))
de_b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(deconv_shape1[4].value))
output_shape=x.get_shape().as_list()
output_shape[1] *= 2
output_shape[2] *= 2
output_shape[3] *= 2 
output_shape[4] = deconv_shape1[4].value
output_shape=np.asarray(output_shape)
output_shape=tfConv3DBackpropInputV2.convert_to_tensor(output_shape)
print(type(output_shape))
x = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(x, de_W1, output_shape, strides=[1, 2, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")
x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,de_b1)
first_down_layer=x
```

x is of type int32.

I get the error as mentioned in tensorflow. What I am doing wrong, as I am not even calling `Conv3DBackpropInputV2()`.

I am a newbie to tensorflow, please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a prefix, why don't you use the ready-made conv3d_transpose layer, [`tf.layers.conv3d_transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv3d_transpose), why are you trying to put it together yourself with all these moving parts? But hey, maybe you have a good reason. So:

`output_shape` is of type int64. Run this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.zeros( ( 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ) )
b = a.get_shape().as_list()
c = np.asarray( b )
print( c.dtype )
```

will output

> int64

So do this when converting to array:

```
output_shape = np.asarray( output_shape, dtype = np.int32 )
```

That should fix it.